# How can I set the output of Int32.TryParse to a null if it cannot parse a string?

Tags: c#

I have a variable

```
int? a = Int32.TryParse(b);
```

How can I make it that a becomes a null if b is found not to be an integer?

Comment: What do you want `a`’s value to be otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
        int? a = int.TryParse(b, out var value) ? value : (int?) null;
```

you should use var instead of int?

```
        var a = int.TryParse(b, out var value) ? value : (int?) null;
```